# Aggregate list on each lambda async execution

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda

To get the list of people in all de classrooms in different sections I use the following:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<People>> GetAll()
{
    var _sections= new List<string>() {"101", "102"}; 
    var people = _sections.Select(async section =>
    {
        var response = await SendRequestAsync<Classroom>(HttpMethods.GET, $"{section}/{_sectionUrl}");
        return response?.PeopleList; //issue
    });

    return await Task.WhenAll(people);
}
```

The object `Classroom` contains a property is `IEnumerable<People>` `PeopleList` that contains the list of people of the classroom.
Can't compile this code:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<_People>[]' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<_People>'. An explicit
> conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I need to be able to gather the list of people in the select in a way that I can aggregate the list with each iteration of the section.

Comment: As I told you the previous time you posted the same question: That is not what the error says. You don't have an `IEnumerable<Task<IEnumerable<People>>`, and it's not expecting an `IEnumerable<Task<People>>`. You also don't have any casts.

Comment: I am not following, could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Everything you've claimed about what the error message says isn't possible with the code that you have.  You should provide an accurate summary (or better yet, simply a direct quote) of what the error message is.  Either that or this isn't an accurate summary of your real code, in which case, you need to fix that.

Comment: I just added the real error of the compiler. A solution I have devised is to add this to the Select:
`.SelectMany(x => x.Result);`
but then it is not asynchronous anymore

Comment: What is the type of the `PeopleList` property?

Comment: @DanielV `await Task.WhenAll(people)` is the thing the error message is telling you is the wrong type, not `people`.  That is what you need to flatten.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have updated the question it is IEnumerable<People>

Comment: @Servy Yes exactly to flatten is the issue itself, do you still think the downvote and closed status is deserved?

Comment: @DanielV The duplicate tells you exactly how to flatten an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to an `IEnumerable<T>` which is exactly what the error you have is telling you you need to do.  You just do that.  Why do you think it's *not* a suitable close reason, and why do you think your question is well researched, clear (given how much everyone has had to fight you to even get you to post clear code and error descriptions) and useful?

Comment: I understand the purpose is to allow somebody to answer my question, at this point it is clear what is required.

Comment: Could you check if this solves the problem? `return (await Task.WhenAll(people)).SelectMany(x => x);`